# Monitoring for the spark-jobserver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I'm currently working with spark-jobserver, and when the spark-jobserver goes down my app just stop working but I don't get notified

There is a health check to spark-jobserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service goes down, it also wouldn't notify. Therefore, there isn't a built-in option for this.

Ideally you'd use external monitoring like Prometheus Blackbox exporter, Nagios, or simply `cron` to `curl`/`netcat` your service.